# Linux→Windows の telnet 時の文字化け解消法

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, encoding

Ubuntu 16.04 から Windows 7に telnet した際、日本語が文字化けしてしまいます。解消方法を教えていただけないでしょうか?

Windows→Linux の telnet 時の文字コード変更方法は調べたらすぐ見つかったのですが、Linux→Windows の telnet 時の文字コード変更方法が分からず困っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

対 EUC-JP なら x11-utils パッケージの `luit`(1) が使えますが、CP932 では駄目ですね。cocot か jacot をインストールして使いましょう。

- cocot - COde COnverter on Tty

  - https://vmi.jp/software/cygwin/cocot.html
- jacot/README-ja.md at master · saitoha/jacot

  - https://github.com/saitoha/jacot

Answer (score 0):

端末メニューの文字コード設定から、Shift-JIS設定に変更して
見ることはできないでしょうか？